# Can a vanilla Magento shop be configured to work without Javascript?

Tags: magento2, javascript

The design philosophy of [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) (and indirectly [RESTfulness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) as well) suggests that a website should work without Javascript (or CSS).
I just tried out a vanilla Luma Magento 2.4.3 store. I could browse around and look at categories, products etc., but the essential *add to cart* button was disabled, so I could not purchase anything. That made me wonder: Can Magento be configured to work without Javascript at all?

Comment: Related SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038369/magento-javascript-reliance-huge-usability-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as the checkout is rendered with Javascript you would need to do a lot of custom development and/or use a third party module which does not use Javascript.